# Protobuf-net deserialization issue

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have created below models in c#.net with protobuf is giving below error

> Attempted to read past the end of the stream

Please find sample class code below

```
[ProtoContract]
    public class Response
    {
        public Response()
        {
            TopAlert = Enumerable.Empty<Alert>();
            InlineAlert = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Alert>>();
        }

        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public IEnumerable<Alert> TopAlert { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<Alert>> InlineAlert { get; set; }

    }


    [ProtoContract]
    public class Alert
    {
         [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string Message { get; set; }
         [ProtoMember(2)]
        public int Level { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: There is no stream reading in the code you posted. Can you post a [mcve] including serialization and deserialization code?

Comment: Also, take care to post the *correct* code as the code in your question won't compile. The `AlertsResponse` is either missing a return type or it is supposed to be the constructor in which case it should be named `Response`. Additionally, you're assigning a dictionary to the `TopAlert` property, and this statement should probably refer to the `InlineAlert` property instead. In short, when you minimize the code, make sure it is still representing your problem and doesn't have its own problems such as these.

Comment: Hi; I'd love to help here (I'm the library author), but this doesn't show enough code to reproduce what you're seeing. Please show how we can get this symptom.